# Xcode Autolayout: Place a label next to a dynamic label at a constant distance

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Check out the loading date label. It could be '2 May' or '24 December'. 
[image]

I want to display the label 'days remaining' after it. Since the width of 'loading date' is dynamic, via auto layout I haven't been able to place 'days remaining' after it. It stays at a fixed distance.

How to adjust it in xcode, using autolayout?

I've been able to achieve it via code by disabling autolayout. However with iOS 7 coming up and autolayout would be essential to maintain iOS 6 and 7 at the same time, I thought it would be a good time to do it with autolayout.

Comment: My eyes are bleeding.

Comment: @iWasRobbed :)
It looks better with the gradient, trust me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the spacing between your two labels is set to auto and that your days remaining label is left aligned.  I suggest keeping a constraint between the trailing edge of your days remaining and the superview, but lowering the priority a bit.  The goal there is to ignore it when the label should be far away from the superview, but not clip or go outside of the visible area when the date is very long.

You may also need to increase the content hugging priority of the date label and/or decrease the compression resistance of your days remaining label.

You may get better insight into what your labels are doing by setting the background color on them temporarily.  The goal is to see how large your labels are, where the text is in the label, and where the spaces are.  If there are large gaps between the labels that will help you figure out where to add constraints or adjust the priorities.  If the labels are taking up the full width then it will help you get the alignment set correct.

Comment: How do I set the spacing between two labels?
I tried changing the constraints, but they are always set with relation to the superview.

Comment: "Editor > Size to Fit Content" option finally helped me set the space between two elements.
http://oleb.net/blog/2013/03/things-you-need-to-know-about-cocoa-autolayout/

Comment: Glad you got it worked out!  For the spacing, if you select both labels at the same time, there is a group of three icons in the lower right.  One of them is the pin menu, click it and pick horizontal spacing.  That will add a constraint between the two views.  You can click on it in the storyboard in the properties inspector set the width to auto.  It will set that up automatically if you drag a label next to another and release when it is 'snapped' into position.